how to apply ssl https to netty socketioServer
Spring server run in myip +  8080 port  and nettysocketio server run in commandLineRunner in 8085 port
[SocketConfig.java]
 

@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SocketConfig {

    final private SocketIOConnectListener socketIOConnectListener;
    final private SocketIODisconnectListener socketIODisconnectListener;
    final private SocketIoAddMappingSupporter socketIoAddMappingSupporter;
    final private AuthZListener authZListener;
    @Value("${socket-server.host}")
    private String host;

    @Value("${socket-server.port}")
    private Integer port;

    @SneakyThrows
    @Bean
    public SocketIOServer socketIOServer() {

        com.corundumstudio.socketio.Configuration config = new com.corundumstudio.socketio.Configuration();

        config.setHostname(host);
        config.setPort(port);

        config.setAuthorizationListener(authZListener);
        config.setMaxHttpContentLength(10 * 1024 * 1024);
        config.setMaxFramePayloadLength(10 * 1024 * 1024);
        config.setOrigin("*");
        config.setNeedClientAuth(false);
        SocketIOServer socketIOServer = new SocketIOServer(config);
        socketIOConnectListener.setServer(socketIOServer);
        socketIODisconnectListener.setServer(socketIOServer);
        socketIoAddMappingSupporter.addListener(socketIOServer);
        socketIOServer.addConnectListener(socketIOConnectListener::OnConnect);
        socketIOServer.addDisconnectListener(socketIODisconnectListener::onDisconnect);

        return socketIOServer;
    }
}


SocketIOServerCommandLineRunner.java
 
@Slf4j
@Component
@Order(1)
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SocketIOServerCommandLineRunner implements CommandLineRunner {
    final private SocketIOServer socketIOServer;

    public Integer port = 8085;

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        try {
            KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
            ks.load(new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\박상한\\keystore.jks"), "password".toCharArray());

            try {
                PrivateKey privateKey = (PrivateKey) ks.getKey("1","password".toCharArray()); // 키 별칭과 비밀번호
                if (privateKey!=null){
                    System.out.println("key valid");
                }
                // 비밀번호가 일치하면 privateKey에 값이 할당됩니다.
            } catch (UnrecoverableKeyException e) {
                // 비밀번호가 일치하지 않으면 예외가 발생합니다.
            }
            socketIOServer.getConfiguration().setAllowHeaders("*");

            inputStream = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\박상한\\keystore.jks");
            socketIOServer.getConfiguration().setKeyStore(inputStream);
            socketIOServer.getConfiguration().setKeyStorePassword("password");
             socketIOServer.start();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("키 저장소 로드 오류", e);
        } finally {
            if (inputStream != null) {
                try {
                    inputStream.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

    }
}


client
[socket.js]
socket = io('myip:8085', {


     rejectUnauthorized:false,
    autoConnect: true,
    reconnection: true
});
 

index.js:83
   GET https://myip:8085/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=P0788Hq net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

i applied ssl spirng server and netty socketio server both.
spring server serves static files and dynamic files. the files served correctly. but when client socket connect error::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR  index.js:83
   GET https://myip:8085/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=P07G5ka net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR   how can i fix it?

i try remove socketio server https. but Mixed Content The page at ' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint ' '. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over error  i added html code     
but the error exist.
how can i apply ssl to socketio server? is netty socketio's corundumstudio.socketioserver is not accept p12, jks certificate files? or there is othere way to apply ssl?
my nettysocketio version =      implementation 'com.corundumstudio.socketio:netty-socketio:2.0.9'
client:  socketio-client  = 2.5.0
